# Angular 5: ngFor with nested select options

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an array of objects. These objects have the property versions. Versions is an array of strings.

I iterate over the objects. For every objects i want to have a drop down field with all available versions.

If the user changes the version i want to push the whole object to my changeSelectedItem() function.

I was able to print "[object Object]" to the console. As i can see, [object Object] is already pushed to my function.

How can i implement my desired function?

My HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let object of storeFilesService.objects">
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="a" (click)="checkobject(object)" name="checkbox" [checked]="true">
      </td>
      <td>{{object.id}}</td>
      <td>{{object.name}}</td>
      <td>{{object.version}}
        <select (change)="changeSelectedItem($event.target.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let version of object.versions" value={{object}}>
            {{version}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
```

TS

```
      changeSelectedItem(filterVal: any) {
    console.log(filterVal);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select (change)="changeSelectedItem($event.target.value, object)">
```

As described by @mbppv this fit my needs, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work like that:

```
<tr *ngFor="let object of storeFilesService.objects">
  <td><input type="checkbox" value="a" (click)="checkobject(object)" name="checkbox" [checked]="true">
  </td>
  <td>{{object.id}}</td>
  <td>{{object.name}}</td>
  <td>{{object.version}}
    <select >
      <option *ngFor="let version of object.versions" (click)="changeSelectedItem(version)">
        {{version}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

What has changed:

- Removed (change) on select
- Applied (click)="changeSelectedItem(version)" on option

Comment: I think this does not fit my desired behaviour. I need the current object from the first ngFor and the selected version from the second ngFor. Do u have any idea how to solve this?.

Comment: @Simon not sure if I got it. But the current object from the first ngFor would be just `object`, right? So then you could pass `changeSelectedObject(version, object)`. Or do I missunderstand something?